# How to detect drop outside draggable views in Android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am working on an Android app, and I'm using drag and drop of a view.

I implemented onLongClick (actually using onTouch with a 1.5-second long click threshold) on my view (circle in the screenshot). When a long click is detected, I display two drop regions (imageviews with onDragListener attached separately, green boxes in the screenshot).

My code works fine when my view is dragged and dropped into either one of the drop regions (ACTION_DROP is called), but the problem is, I also need to be able to tell when my circle is dropped outside the drop regions so I can reset the state. In this case, I don't get any callbacks triggered from either of the two drop regions. I don't think I saw any method to call from the view I used startDrag method, either.

Only thing I get from logcat after dropping my view outside any drop regions is this:

> I/ViewRootImpl﹕ Reporting drop result: false

Any way to detect that "drop result: false" from my code? Help would be appreciated!

Screenshot link below:

[image: screenshot]

---------- UPDATE 11/21 ----------

At the time I first posted this question, I was still trying to grasp the high level concepts, but now I realize that I should have included more details.

Here are some code snippets that are used in my app at the moment. By the way, I'm using those views--circle(anchor) and green boxes (dropRegions)--in a Service, not an Activity, so I used WindowManager to add the views.

I still have the same problem, and the main thing I don't get is, ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED and ACTION_DRAG_EXITED were never called. Only ACTION_DROP worked for me so far. Am I still missing something?

Below are relevant parts of code.

Called when the circle is long-clicked (modified a bit after sandrstar's response) :

```java
private void anchorOnLongClick(View view) {
    Log.d("####", "LONG CLICK");
    showAnchorDropRegion();

    ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((String) view.getTag());
    ClipData data = new ClipData((String) view.getTag(),
            new String[]{ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN}, item);

    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
    view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, null, 0);
    setupAnchorDropRegion();
    showAnchorDropRegion();
}
```

Attaching drag listeners to the green boxes:

```java
/* set up the region where anchor can be drag-and-dropped */
private void setupAnchorDropRegion() {
    ivDropRight = new ImageView(this);
    ivDropRight.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dropregion_normal));
    ivDropRight.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            Log.d("####", "onDrag");
            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    // do nothing
                    return true;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    Log.d("####", "DRAG_ENTERED");
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    Log.d("####", "DRAG_EXITED");
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    Log.d("####", "DROP ON: " + event.getX() + ", " + event.getY());
                    hideDropRegion();
                    // initialize anchor locations to the right
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    Log.d("####", "DRAG ENDED");
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

// repeat for ivDropLeft
```

Showing green boxes (drop regions):

```
/* display anchor drop region left and right */
private void showAnchorDropRegion() {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams dropRegionParmas = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            app.dropRegionSize, app.dropRegionSize, 0, 0,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    dropRegionParmas.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.LEFT;
    mWindowManager.addView(ivDropLeft, dropRegionParmas);

    dropRegionParmas.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT;
    mWindowManager.addView(ivDropRight, dropRegionParmas);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Main idea is from this documentation of [DragEvent.getResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/DragEvent.html#getResult%28%29):

> Returns an indication of the result of the drag and drop operation.
>   This method only returns valid data if the action type is
>   ACTION_DRAG_ENDED. The return value depends on what happens after the
>   user releases the drag shadow.

So, after drop, you can obtain result via `getResult()`: if it returns `true` then it has been dropped in some view which accepts drop. Please note that views which accepts drop return `true` to `ACTION_DROP`:

> The View should return true from its onDragEvent(DragEvent) handler or
>   OnDragListener.onDrag() listener if it accepted the drop, and false if
>   it ignored the drop.

Below is some small example, similar to your layout which shows that approach:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private View mCircleView = null;
    private Boolean mDroppedIn = null;

    private View.OnDragListener mLeftDragListener = new View.OnDragListener() {
        private boolean mInView = false;

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(final View v, final DragEvent event) {
            final int action = event.getAction();

            switch (action) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    mDroppedIn = null;
                    mCircleView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_dark);
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    mInView = true;
                    v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_light);
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    mInView = false;
                    v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_dark);
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    mCircleView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (mCircleView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                                mCircleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    reportResult(R.id.leftView, event.getResult());
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    return mInView;
            }

            return true;
        }
    };

    private View.OnDragListener mRightDragListener = new View.OnDragListener() {
        private boolean mInView = false;

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(final View v, final DragEvent event) {
            final int action = event.getAction();

            switch (action) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    mDroppedIn = null;
                    mCircleView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_dark);
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    mInView = true;
                    v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_light);
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    mInView = false;
                    v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_dark);
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    mCircleView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (mCircleView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                                mCircleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    reportResult(R.id.rightView, event.getResult());
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    return mInView;
            }

            return true;
        }
    };

    private void reportResult(final int viewId, final boolean result) {
        if (mDroppedIn == null) {
            mDroppedIn = result;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Dropped in: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mCircleView = findViewById(R.id.circleView);

        mCircleView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(final View v) {
                final ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((String)v.getTag());
                final ClipData dragData = new ClipData((String)v.getTag(),
                        new String[] {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN}, item);

                mCircleView.startDrag(dragData, new CircleShadowBuilder(v), null, 0);
                findViewById(R.id.leftView).setOnDragListener(mLeftDragListener);
                findViewById(R.id.rightView).setOnDragListener(mRightDragListener);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private class CircleShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {

        private final Drawable mShadow;

        CircleShadowBuilder(final View v) {
            super(v);
            mShadow = v.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProvideShadowMetrics(final Point shadowSize, final Point shadowTouchPoint) {
            int width = getView().getWidth();
            int height = getView().getHeight();

            mShadow.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
            shadowSize.set(width, height);
            shadowTouchPoint.set(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawShadow(final Canvas canvas) {
            mShadow.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added more details about the problem I'm having in my edit.

Also, I saw you have edited my original post to display the screenshot. Is that something I missed to do, or do you have a special permission to enable that for me? Thanks!

Comment: @AnotherDev yeah, seems some rep points number is needed to provide images in questions. Regarding question, it's strange, because in my code I receive the events. Might it be related to how you add views?

Answer (score 2):

I hope you already had found a solution.

I was having the same problem. I was trying to detect a drop outside all draggable views.

By looking at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) in the The drag/drop process section I found that **ACTION_DRAG_ENDED** is called when the drag finishes regardless of where the drop occurred.

*"After the user releases the drag shadow, and after the system sends out (if necessary) a drag event with action type ACTION_DROP, the system sends out a drag event with action type ACTION_DRAG_ENDED to indicate that the drag operation is over. This is done regardless of where the user released the drag shadow. The event is sent to every listener that is registered to receive drag events, even if the listener received the ACTION_DROP event."*

So, we can use that.

Your drag listener can know the drop occurred inside a drop-able view with **ACTION_DROP**. And your drag listener can know that the drop ended with **ACTION_DRAG_ENDED**

For anyone interested I have a sample of how to use the drag and drop to move an image between layouts [HandleImage](https://github.com/an-garcia/HandleImage/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/xengar/android/handleimage/ui/DragAndDropActivity.java).

What the sample do is:

1. When the drag starts it hides the image and display only the drag shadow image.
2. When the drop occurs it moves the image into another layout.
3. If the drop is outside any layout it displays the image again where it was at the beginning.

---

### DragAndDropActivity.java

```
package com.xengar.android.handleimage.ui;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder;
import android.view.View.OnDragListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.xengar.android.handleimage.R;

/**
 * DragAndDropActivity
 */
public class DragAndDropActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drag_and_drop);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        /*
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });*/

        findViewById(R.id.myimage1).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.myimage2).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.myimage3).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.myimage4).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.topleft).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.topright).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.bottomleft).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.bottomright).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

    }

    private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                        view);
                view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
        Drawable enterShape = getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.shape_droptarget);
        Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            View view;
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    // do nothing
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    v.setBackgroundDrawable(enterShape);
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
                    view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                    owner.removeView(view);
                    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
                    container.addView(view);
                    //view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
                    // Regardless of valid or invalid drop show it again.
                    // See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/DragEvent.html#ACTION_DRAG_ENDED
                    view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

---

### activity_drag_and_drop.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.xengar.android.handleimage.ui.DragAndDropActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!--<include layout="@layout/content_drag_and_drop" /> -->

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.xengar.android.handleimage.ui.DragAndDropActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_drag_and_drop">

        <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:columnWidth="320dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:rowCount="2"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/topleft"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:background="@drawable/shape" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/myimage1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/gallery_lion" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/topright"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/myimage2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/gallery_lion" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/bottomleft"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/myimage3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/gallery_lion" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/bottomright"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/myimage4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/gallery_lion" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </GridLayout>


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <!--
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" /> -->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another issue I needed to address was keeping track of the drags across the empty space between drag listeners, in case the user didn't drop on a listener, so I could animate the dragged item back to it's start, like a rubber band.

DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION will not fire unless it's over a listener. So I added a drag listener to my FrameLayout, just another view. Now when the user is dragging, I get location updates, store those, and when the user drops I check if FrameLayout caught the drop. That solves your problem and I have my location for the drop whether it was on a wanted drag listener or dropped early in which case I rubber band the original item back to it's start.